# Asymptotic expansion of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics

What are the first terms of the asymptotic expansion of
$$
I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}dx\ ?
$$
Using the dominated convergence theorem to 
$$
n\bigg(I_n-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{x}{n}}{x(1+x^2)}dx\bigg)
$$ 
I obtain $I_n \sim \frac{\pi}{2n}$. But I have no idea for the second term.

**ADD-ON:**

Thank you for the beautiful answers.

1) Does there exist an elementary method (without complex analysis) for obtain the second term ? Indeed, the question is provided by a elementary course on real analysis.

2) I guess the first term with the equivalence $\sin(x) \underset{0}{\sim} x$. Why intuitively the approximation $\sin(x) \approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ does not give the second term ?

Comment: Not sure if it defeats the purpose of the exercise, but the integral can be done exactly as a contour integral.

Comment: In case it's of use: $I_n = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-1/n})$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen it can probably also be done cleanly as a real integral if we allow ourselves to use Differential Equations

Comment: @brevanellefsen I buy it but don't know exactly what you're referring to. Would be interested if you added it to the answer mix. (Still don't know if exact solution is what op wants although it certainly answers the headline question.)

Comment: My feeling is that we can consider the integral $f(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt)}{x(1+x^2)} d x$ and use the derivation theorem under the integral two times in order to obtain a link between the second derivative $f''$ and $f$. But I does not know solve the differential equation and it is not elementary.

Answer (score 9):

Note that $$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x/n\right)}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x/n\right)}{x}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin\left(x/n\right)}{1+x^{2}}dx$$ and the first integral is easy to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x/n\right)}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{u}du=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ for the secon integral we may observe that $$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin\left(x/n\right)}{1+x^{2}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\textrm{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{xi/n}}{1+x^{2}}dx\right)$$ then taking as path the upper semicircumference and noting that the integral over the semicircle vanish as the radius $R\rightarrow\infty$ we get by residue theorem$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{xi/n}}{1+x^{2}}dx=2\pi i\underset{x=i}{\textrm{Res}}\left(\frac{xe^{xi/n}}{1+x^{2}}\right)=\pi ie^{-1/n}$$ so $$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin\left(x/n\right)}{1+x^{2}}dx=\color{red}{-\frac{\pi e^{-1/n}}{2}}$$ as wanted. Now the expansion should be very simple.

Comment: Well done, for sure.

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an answer;*

We can get the antiderivative first using $$\frac 1{x(1+x^2)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 (x-i)}-\frac{1}{2 (x+i)}$$ and so, we face the problem of $$\int \frac {\sin(\frac xn)}{x-a}dx=\sin \left(\frac{a}{n}\right) \text{Ci}\left(\frac{x-a}{n}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{a}{n}\right) \text{Si}\left(\frac{x-a}{n}\right)$$ where appears the sine and cosine integrals. Then, assuming $n>0$, 
 $$\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin(\frac xn)}{x-a}dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \text{Si}\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)+\pi \right) \cos
   \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)-\text{Ci}\left(-\frac{a}{n}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$$ and **I am stuck** with the limits when $x \to \infty$ and $a=\pm i$.

Cheating, that is to say using a CAS, I have been more than surprised to learn that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}   \left(1-e^{-1/n}\right)$$ as spaceisdarkgreen reported in his/her comment while I was typing. Frm here, the expansion to any order becomes simple.

As spaceisdarkgreen also commented, I suppose that a contour integral would be a nice and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x\left(1+n^2x^2\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac14\int_{-\infty-\frac{i}{2n}}^{\infty-\frac{i}{2n}}\left(\frac2x-\frac1{x-\frac{i}{n}}-\frac1{x+\frac{i}{n}}\right)\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{8i}\int_{\gamma^+}\left(\frac2x-\frac1{x-\frac{i}{n}}\color{#CCC}{-\frac1{x+\frac{i}{n}}}\right)e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&-\frac1{8i}\int_{\gamma^-}\left(\color{#CCC}{\frac2x-\frac1{x-\frac{i}{n}}}-\frac1{x+\frac{i}{n}}\right)e^{-ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi4\left(2-e^{-1/n}\right)+\pi\left(-e^{-1/n}\right)\tag{4}\\[12pt]
&=\frac\pi2\left(1-e^{-1/n}\right)\tag{5}\\[9pt]
&\sim\frac\pi2\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{6n^3}-\dots\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: the integrand is even then substitute $x\mapsto nx$
$(2)$: partial fractions and move the contour down $\frac{i}{2n}$
$(3)$: close the contours with arcs whose integrals vanish and $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ the greyed out parts have no residue inside the corresponding contours
$(4)$: use residues to compute the contour integrals
$(5)$: algebra
$(6)$: give the asymptotic expansion (actually, the start of the Taylor series)

The contours mentioned above are
$$
\gamma^+=\left[-R-\frac{i}{2n},R-\frac{i}{2n}\right]\cup \left(Re^{i\pi[0,1]}-\frac{i}{2n}\right)
$$
and
$$
\gamma^-=\left[-R-\frac{i}{2n},R-\frac{i}{2n}\right]\cup \left(Re^{-i\pi[0,1]}-\frac{i}{2n}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Marco's answer, we have
$$\mathcal{L}\left(\sin\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{1+n^2 s^2},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\right) = 1-\cos(s) \tag{1}$$
hence
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{n(1-\cos s)}{1+n^2 s^2}\,ds = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos\frac{s}{n}}{1+s^2}\,ds = \frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{s}{n}}{1+s^2}\,ds \tag{2} $$
where $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{s}{n}}{1+s^2}\,ds = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-1/n}$ is a straightforward consequence of the residue theorem.
The full asymptotic expansion of $I_n$ is so given by
$$\boxed{\ I_n = \color{red}{\frac{\pi-1}{2}}+\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m!\,n^m}}.\,}\tag{3} $$