# Finding the following integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm looking for the following limit. I was thinking maybe the limit is $\pi/2$. However, I cannot pass the limit inside the integral. Maybe the sequence is uniformly convergent, but I cannot prove it.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{n\sin{(\frac{x}{n})}}{x(1+x^2)}dx.$$

Comment: We have $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. Now apply the dominated convergence theorem to pass the limit inside the integral.

Comment: See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326942/asymptotic-expansion-of-int-0-infty-frac-sin-fracxnx1x2dx